# How to calculate 2^59 mod 247 (on Casio FX-9860 GII)

Tags: function, calculator, equation, modulo

does anyone know how to calculate this?

Maybe a function in my calculator?

I tried to solve it with my calculator in a normal way, like typing it in, but it returned an error back (guess the number is just to large).

Regards

TC.

Comment: 59=32+16+8+3. 2\*\*32 mod 247 = 139, 2\*\*16 mod 247 = 81, 2\*\*8 mod 247 = 9, 2\*\*3 mod 247 = 8. 2\*\*59 mod 247 = (139 * 81 * 9 * 8) mod 247 = 241.

Answer (score 0):

Just do MOD_Exp(2,59,247)
MOD_Exp can be found under num which is under the option menu